# Check if any character in one string appears in another

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string of text

```
hfHrpphHBppfTvmzgMmbLbgf
```

I have separated this string into two half's

```
hfHrpphHBppf,TvmzgMmbLbgf
```

I'd like to check if any of the characters in the first string, also appear in the second string, and would like to class lowercase and uppercase characters as separate (so if string 1 had `a` and string 2 had `A` this would not be a match).

and the above would return:

```
f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
split_text = ['hfHrpphHBppf', 'TvmzgMmbLbgf']

for char in split_text[0]:
    if char in split_text[1]:
        print(char)
```

There is probably a better way to do it, but this a quick and simple way to do what you want.

Edit:

```py
split_text = ['hfHrpphHBppf', 'TvmzgMmbLbgf']
found_chars = []

for char in split_text[0]:
    if char in split_text[1] and char not in found_chars:
        found_chars.append(char)
        print(char)
```

There is almost certainly a better way of doing this, but this is a way of doing it with the answer I already gave

Comment: If the original string is still a `string` and not a `list`, you can convert it to a list like this `split_text = og_string.split(',')`

Comment: this is great thanks, although an issue I'm seeing is if multiple characters appear in both strings, for example `['BzRmmzZHzVBzgVQmZ', 'LPtqqffPqWqJmPLlL']` - using the code on this list returns me `m m m` when I only need it to return each character the repeats once. so if I also had a list like `['sabbC', 'bbaxZ']` I would want it to return `b a`

Comment: @Conor ah I didn't realise you only wanted to get 1 of the shared characters, I've made an edit, but as it says, there is almost certainly a better way of doing it than what I provided but since I don't do this sort of thing I wouldn't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "in" word.

something like this :

```
for i in range(len(word1) : 
   if word1[i] in word2 : 
      print(word[i])
```

Not optimal, but it should print you all the letter in common

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `set()` and `intersection`

```
text = "hfHrpphHBppf,TvmzgMmbLbgf"
text = text.split(",")
print(set(text[0]).intersection(set(text[1])))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension in order to check if letters from string a appears in string b.

```
a='hfHrpphHBppf'
b='TvmzgMmbLbgf'
c=[x for x in a if x in b]
print(' '.join(set(c)))
```

then output will be:

```
f
```

But you can use for,too. Like:

```
a='hfHrpphHBppf'
b='TvmzgMmbLbgf'
c=[]
for i in a:
  if i in b:
  c.append(i)
print(set(c))
```